# Get current state in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Newbie to the whole ionic and angular scene.
I used the ionic creator to generate the view files.
My goal is to check if the user is logged in before proceeding in to a tab.
However, before getting to the authentication part, I wanted to check which window the user is on.
I am trying to use a simple alert/console.log to identify the progress.

Below is my code.

```
.controller('adminPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function     ($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $state) {
    //alert($state.current.name);
    $scope.currState = $state;
    var currentState = $state.current.name; 
    console.log($state);
}])
```

I have come across the below error which i cant seem to make heads or tails.
"ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined".

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Even the console.log($state); command returns "undefined".

Comment: Did you include `ui.router` as dependency?

Comment: Ionic platform adds the ui.router dependency automatically. Which ionic version are you using?

Comment: Try to to add `$rootScope` dependency

Comment: by doing $scope.currState = $state; you're not doing anything. Change that to  $scope.currState = $state.current.name; Then you can console.log($scope.currState) edit: i've just seen you commented that alert, so that doesnt alert anything?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you are defining more depencencies than you are actually using.

You can either fix it by removing the reference to $rootScope on the function definition or adding it to the list of dependencies.

```
.controller('adminPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
   //alert($state.current.name);
   $scope.currState = $state;
   var currentState = $state.current.name; 
   console.log($state);
}])
```

OR

```
.controller('adminPageCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $state) {
   //alert($state.current.name);
   $scope.currState = $state;
   var currentState = $state.current.name; 
   console.log($state);
}])
```

And since you are using the name of the dependencies to name the variables inside the function, you could also use Implicit Annotation (please take a look on the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di):

```
.controller('adminPageCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
   //alert($state.current.name);
   $scope.currState = $state;
   var currentState = $state.current.name; 
   console.log($state);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You've need `$rootScope` dependency. Without them you will receive another list of arguments.

```
.controller('adminPageCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $state) {
    $scope.currState = $state;
    var currentState = $state.current.name; 
    console.log($state);
}])
```